# Proto Compilation Error - No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, cmd, compilation

I am trying to compile Protoc library but It just keeps giving me the error of No Such Directory even though it is there

I am following [Google's Photobuf compilation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) steps
I have added Protoc to PATH environment variable as well.

But it simply won't see the **object_detection/protos directory**

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

[image]

The directory and the files are clearly there

[image]

Comment: Did you add Libraries to PYTHONPATH: (From tensorflow/models/research/)
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim`

Comment: Did you try using a backslash \`\\` rather than a forward slash `/` for the path to the files?

Comment: @vijaym I think that is for Unix not Windows. ->lit Yes I did. Black slashes won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same issue with you.
I have been installed protoc with anaconda3,but it is useless.

This is my solution:
Head to the [protoc releases page](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases) and download the protoc-3.4.0-win32.zip, extract it, and you will find protoc.exe in the bin directory.

Move this to models/research folder [tensorflow model project](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/)

Next,you can use the protoc command like

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

[Reference linking](https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/)

Comment: After spending couple of hours on this - your solution saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same problem using the latest protoc version for windows: 3.5.0.   On a whim I tried using the slightly older version (3.4.0) and got it to work using the exact same instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Use 3.4.0 version and run from object_detectionprotoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.