# Running protoc compiler for a large number of protoc files from command line

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have about 150 proto files and am trying to compile them in Windows 10. For one of them called a.proto, in the Windows command line I do:

protoc -I. --python_out =. .\a.proto

Of course I wish not to type this 150 times for different files. What is the easiest way to compile all the proto files?

Answer (score 1):

With Git Bash the use of wildcard to execute `protoc` for each .proto file in the directory seem to work for me: (not in cmd / powershell)

```
protoc ./*.proto --python_out=.
```

Other answers here suggest to use version 3.4.0 to use wildcard, I haven't tried it, but it does not work with 3.6.0 for me. See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47815543/10455554)

Maybe one of the solutions in one of this two questions is a better fit [protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46491112/10455554) or [How to compile multiple proto files in single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949801/how-to-compile-multiple-proto-files-in-single-command/24965532)